# Diango 1.6 How about this way of create an object for a model which has two ForeignKey fields?

Tags: django

There are three models: User, Question and Answer.

My way can works--override the Answer modelform's `save` method, pass two objects(question and user to it.

I am not sure whether this is the official way or best way. Or is there some good tutorial for this situation, Thanks.

This is the code:

```
#settings.py

#ROOT urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myauth.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^questions/', include('questions.urls',namespace='questions')),
)

#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('questions.views',  
    url(r'^(?P<question_pk>\d+)/detail/$',
        'detail',
        {'template_name': 'questions/detail.html'},
        name='detail'),
                       )

#models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField()

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    title = models.CharField()  
    content = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):

    #user create an anwer to a question
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)  
    content = models.TextField() 

#forms.py
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['content']

    #this is my way
    #pass two objects:user and question to it
    def save(self,user,question,commit=True,):
        answer = super(AnswerForm,self).save(commit=False)
        answer.user = user
        answer.question = question
        if commit:
            answer.save()
        return answer

#views.py 
def detail(request,
    question_pk,
    template_name,
    answer_create_form=AnswerForm):

    """detail to show a question,contains:
    1.question's title and content.
    2.all answers(represented by field 'content')to this question
    3.a form for create an answer to this question
    """

    #question object is identified by question_pk from the url string.
    #along with request.user, both will be passed to the form to
    #create answer objects.
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_pk)
    user = request.user

    #all answers to this question
    answers = question.answer_set.all()
    form=None
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = answer_create_form(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(user=user,question=question)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        else:
            form = answer_create_form()
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, locals(),)

#questions/detail.html

#rest ommitted...
{% if form %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="回答" />
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields). So you should de something like:

```
question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_pk)
user = request.user
(....)
if user.is_authenticated():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer = Answer(question=question, user=user)
        form = AnswerForm(data=request.POST, instance=answer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        (....)
```